# Assign a glyphicon to a class in bootstrap 2.3.2

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-2

In `bootstrap 2.3.2`, How can I assign a `glyphicon` to a class, so when I use that class, the glyphicon will appear where it's used.

**Example:**

```
.heart {
  assign icon-heart here
}
```

Usage:

```
<span class="heart"></span>
```

**Output**

The heart icon from the sprite appears here.

Is something like this possible?

Later I intend changing the `.heart` to `.no-heart` using jquery, and I;ll get another icon there. That's the whole idea.

Comment: Why don't you just add the glyphicon class? Something like `<span class="heart the-glyphicon-you-want"></span>`

Answer (score 0):

The css for twitter bootstrap icon-heart is as follows:

```
.icon-heart {
    background-position: -96px 0;
}
[class^=icon-], [class*=' icon-'] {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 14px;
    height: 14px;
    margin-top: 1px;
    line-height: 14px;
    vertical-align: text-top;
    background-image: url(../img/glyphicons-halflings.png);
    background-position: 14px 14px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```